# List WinXP Files with Too Long Filenames

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp

Can you recommend a way to list files on a WinXP disk that have a total file name (drive+folder+subfolder+filename+ext) greater than some value or MAX_PATH? Ideally this would be in batch or VB script. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
if "%~1%~2"=="%~2%~1" (
    echo Usage: drive maxlength
    echo Example: %0 d: 200
    goto :EOF
)
for /F %%A in ('dir /S/B/A:-D "%~d1\*" 2^>nul') do call :chkpath "%%~A" %2
goto :EOF
:chkpath
set #=%~1%
set len=0
:longer
if defined # (set "#=%#:~1%"&set /A len += 1&goto longer)
if %len% GTR %2 echo.%~1
goto :EOF
```

I would imagine that windows scripting host is faster...